# Ruby selenium 2.0 cannot get attribute value from select box

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="input-with-icon no-icon">
  <select class="hidden-input js-duration-dropdown" value="4 hours">
```

When I use Ruby selenium web driver to get the attribute value

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@class=\"input-with-icon no-icon\"]/select[@class=\"hidden-input js-duration-dropdown\"]").attribute("value")
```

I got empty string ""

However if I use JS in Chrome console

```
document.evaluate("//div[@class=\"input-with-icon no-icon\"]/select[@class=\"hidden-input js-duration-dropdown\"]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.getAttribute("value")
```

I am able to get the value "4 hours" printed. 
I don't understand what causes the problem. Is there anyone run into the same issue? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You should implement some wait.. may be it doesn't loaded fully when you are going to find and get attribute...

Answer (score 0):

The class on the select element in your html implies that it is hidden, not displayed.  WebDriver will not allow you to get the attribute of the element if it is hidden.  Try using Javascript to set the element visible, then get it's value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however setting the element visible did not solve the issue.

Comment: could you show us the code you use to set the element visible?

Comment: Here's the code I use:   
`

driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.visibility = \"visible\";', element)
`

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it work by injecting JavaScript function:

```
attributes = driver.execute_script('var items = {}; 
for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) 
{ items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = 
arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;', element)

return attributes
```

I still didn't know why selenium couldn't get the attribute value.